# Circle rolling on a circle

Tags: mathematics

Consider a circle with radius 3. Rolling around this circle is another circle, with radius 1. How many times has the little circle made a full turn when it has returned to it´s starting point?

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is actually...

> 4 times.

There's a video that demonstrates it far better than I could, but here's the synopsis:

> This was an SAT question that everyone got wrong. The supposed answer was 3, following the math of $\frac{2\pi{(3)}}{2\pi{(1)}}$, which would yield 3. But as the video shows, after just one quarter rotation, the rotating circle has completed one turn. It takes a full four turns for it to complete. In fact, the formula used is: When radius A is $1/n$ radius B, the number of rotations will be $n+1$.

See the video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kN3AOMrnEUs).

Comment: Interesting. After going over the simulation in my head, it does make sense.

Comment: rolling around the inside of the circle it would be only 2 times, for much the same reason,